# How to specify "namespace" and "conformsto" attribute to APIs for services developed using ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, asmx, servicestack.redis

We are currently in process of converting our legacy web services (asmx) into REST APIs layer developed using ServiceStack platform.

There exists a few Web services having the namespace and Binding ConformsTo attributes specified in asmx. Following is one such example:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://ourcustomsite.com/externalServices")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
```

How can we set them in their ServiceStack counterpart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to ServiceStack's [SOAP Support](http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support) it only supports changing the namespace using .NET DataContract attributes which should be specified for each namespace that your DTOs (aka ServiceModels) are in, e.g:

```
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://ourcustomsite.com/externalServices",
           ClrNamespace = "MyApp.ServiceModel.Operations")]
[assembly: ContractNamespace("http://ourcustomsite.com/externalServices",
           ClrNamespace = "MyApp.ServiceModel.Types")]
```

You'll also want to specify your custom namespace on:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    WsdlServiceNamespace = "http://ourcustomsite.com/externalServices",
});
```

ServiceStack's SOAP bindings are not customizable and is not designed to be used to conform to a profile of an existing SOAP Service. SOAP clients need to use the `/soap11` and `/soap12` WSDLs to generate the WCF Service Reference clients or even better the generic [Soap12ServiceClient](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client#httpwebrequest-service-clients) which can use your Services existing typed DTOs instead of a WSDL generated proxy.

#### Avoid SOAP for new Projects

Usage of SOAP should be [considered legacy](https://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack) and limited to situations where their usage is mandated. [Add ServiceStack Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) together with ServiceStack's [generic C#/.NET Service Clients](http://docs.servicestack.net/csharp-client) offers a much [faster, simpler, versatile and resilient](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#advantages-over-wcf) alternative to SOAP that can be utilized in a [number of different C#/.NET Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile) in a [number of different languages](http://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#supported-languages) and should be the preferred solution when its usage is an option.